# Assign a PID to SimpleHTTPServer and kill process from script

Tags: python, process, pid, simplehttpserver, taskkill

I need to assign a **PID** to a **python script** packaged to an **.exe** with **Py2Installer**.

The script starts a **SimpleHTTPServer** loop and opens a page in the current dir; **I need to check if it's already running before it starts** and stop it gracefully in that case.

Here's the code:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import webbrowser

PORT = 8945

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

webbrowser.open('http://localhost:8945')

# print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

The problem is that I don't want to stop any "python" instance on a production machine and my **taskkill** can't view any SimpleHTTPServer process ID (because there is none, in fact).

Is it possible to run a similar check inside my script or do you know any workaround?

Thank you in advance.